# Jenkins Slave Remote FS root configuration not taking effect

Tags: jenkins, slave

I am trying to change the work space folder in which my jenkins build runs on. From the documentation and other resources I have set this in the node as shown below:

[image: Jenkins Slave FS root]

When I run the build it's still pulling to the original folder /home/jenkins-slave/workspace. Is there somewhere else this needs to be configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you configured it correctly.

The only thing you still have to do is to restart the slave by going to the master -> Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes -> choose the relevant node and then hit "Disconnect" and then "Relaunch slave".

If it's a Windows slave then restart the Jenkins service in the relevant slave.

Comment: Thanks Itai, my configuration seems to reset back to normal when I do that, but I'm guessing that this is a different problem that I will begin to debug. Thanks for confirming I'm on the right track.

Comment: You’re welcome mate